# Stripe API transfer to Bank Account

Tags: stripe-payments

Does anyone know how to transfer to a bank account using Stripe API?

In the Stripe Reference it looks very simple: https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_transfer

```
stripe.Transfer.create(
  amount=400,
  currency="usd",
  destination="acct_19MKfXGyOv0GIG6Z",
  description="Transfer for test@example.com"
)
```

I don't understand where the destination id comes from. How can I get the destination id of a bank account?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are two types of transfers with Stripe:

- internal transfers, from a Stripe platform account to one of its connected accounts. This is known as a ["special-case transfer"](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/special-case-transfers).
- external transfers, from a Stripe account to its associated bank account.

If you only have a single bank account for a given currency, you can use the special value `"default_for_currency"`  for the [`destination`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_transfer-destination) parameter.

E.g. if you run this code:

```
stripe.Transfer.create(
  amount=400,
  currency="usd",
  destination="default_for_currency",
  description="Transfer for test@example.com"
)
```

then $4.00 would be sent to your USD bank account.

**EDIT:** On newer API versions (>= [2017-04-06](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2017-04-06)), "internal transfers" are now simply known as "transfers", and "external transfers" are now known as "payouts". Cf. [this doc page](https://stripe.com/docs/transfer-payout-split) for more information.

Comment: If I want to transfer to a bank account that is not my bank account in Stripe, is that possible? I have the Routing Number and the Account Number

Comment: No, that is not possible, as it wouldn't be compliant with Stripe's services agreement -- you can only add bank accounts that are owned by the same entity that owns the Stripe account. If you need to accept payments on behalf of third parties, you should take a look at [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect).

Answer (score 1):

I have to use the below code in my existing project

```
Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
  // Create a Charge:
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'amount' => 1300,
        'currency' => 'GBP',
        'customer' => 'cus_FM5OdvqpYD7AbR', // customer id
        'transfer_group' => date('y-m-d_h:i:s'),
        'transfer_data' => [
            'destination' => 'acct_1EuyLUIpWjdwbl8y', // destination id
            'amount' => 700
        ]
    ]);

    dd($charge);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts
this above link will let you know how to get bank account id

```
stripe.accounts.create({
  country: "US",
  type: "custom"
}).then(function(acct) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

you can get

this code will give acc. id in response that you can use in destination.